# Doesn't update Text in database log = log + $a123

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a big problem I don't know how I can solved this...
I am trying to update on database `poletextu set log = log + $a123` but this down code doesn't work
this doesn't work

```
$a123 = '(fghg)';

mysql_query("update ".$db.".poletextu set log = log + ".$a123." where cos = ".$cos['id']." limit 1");
```

this down code working >>

```
mysql_query("update ".$db.".poletextu set log = 'asdasd' where cos = ".$cos['id']." limit 1");
```

and this too working

```
 $a123 = '123';
but when i change $a123 to text value this dont update 
    mysql_query("update ".$db.".poletextu set log = log + '$a123' where cos = ".$cos['id']." limit 1");
```

anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: $log = "log"; 
mysql_query("update ".$db.".poletextu set log = ' .$log. + .$a123.' where cos = ".$cos['id']." limit 1");

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar thanks but i want every update adding more value like first update + $a123 and next update + $123 = fghgfghg on text database now its just = $a123 how i can add this?

Comment: Why you marked as duplicate this Question can i know

Comment: anyone cant help me ;]

Comment: First Unmarked the Ans As a Duplicate .. Then We Can Help You

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar i dont know i edited my post. only have problems on update text value from $a123 = 'abc' doesnt work but with $a123 = '123' working

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar posible insert where id?

Comment: wait.. i m trying ..

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar this is possible? because when i trying log = log + '123' it dont separate its just 123+123 = 246 here is problem so why a+a = 0 ;(

Comment: bcoz its taking as a string ..